# Clustering data with python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, cluster-analysis

I try to cluster my dataset with python and scikit-learn. It's an exercise of my University. The dataset looks like this:

```
StationNr        A1        A2        A3        A4        A5        A6        A7        A8        A9        A10        A11        A12

  
    0        2.45        4.32        3.5      1.89      2.87      4.34      2.67      3.90      3.97       2.61       3.01       2.95
  
  1200       3.01        2.95        3.53     1.8       2.8       4.3       2.67      2.87      2.45       4.32       3.53       2.95
```

The column "StationNr" has the following different values:
[   0, 1200,  900,  100,  400,  300,  600,  200, 1100,  500,
1000,  800,  700] 
If there is a zero in "StationNr", it means that the product is good. The other numbers has the meaning, on which station the product declared bad. 
The columns "A%" has the following different values and the columns reprensent a processing station: 
 [ 2.017,  1.767,  0.987, ..., 24.083, 18.977,  4.904] 
There are about 4000 different values for "A1". This values are the duration of the processing on the station.

Now, I want to know, is there a cluster in duration of processing on stations (A1, A2, A3 ... ,A11 ,A12), for example a single value or the combination of values, that's result is a bad or a good product. Good products has the "StationNr" == 0  and bad products has the "StationNr" != 0.

I select the k-Means algorithm to explore the data and i don't how-to get my exercise in combination with k-Means in python code.

Maybe k-Means is not the best algorithm for this case, then I will be happy, if you suggest a better algorithm.

I'm very new in this topic and will be happy, if you help me to clustering my data.

Best regards

Christian

Comment: SciPy has [k-means functionality](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html). So [does scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are almost more than 10 algorithms given in `sklearn` for the clustering purpose. For example **Birch,DBSCAN, K-Means, Spectral** and so on. You ca nfidn a complete list [here in the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

You just have to put the data to the model and apply the `fit` method. You'll also need the necessary parametrs to be pased such as number of clusters in `k-means`.

I suppose this is the a dataframe and I'll name it `df` so a working example can be something like this:

```
X = df.values

from sklearn.cluster import Birch, KMeans, SpectralClustering, AgglomerativeClustering, DBSCAN

brc = Birch(n_clusters=None) # with int value, it'll perform Agglomerative Clustering
brc.fit(X)
brc.predict(X) # array of points belonging to unique clusters

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
kmeans.labels_ # array of clusters according to indices

clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2, assign_labels="discretize",random_state=0).fit(X)
clustering.labels_  # label of each data point belonging to the cluster

clustering = AgglomerativeClustering().fit(X)
clustering.labels_

clustering = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=2).fit(X)
clustering.labels_
```

Do try and let me know. If it helped, please up vote and accept as answer.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I try the code and it works, but the spectralclustering doesn't work. There I get an Error "Graph is not fully connected, spectral embedding may not work as expected", but I am looking for the cause. 
Now, I have the returns, but how can I interpret them and process further?

Comment: For example the result of the BIRCH algorithm has 15295 unique values. That mean, the data has 15295 cluster, right? That's alot, because I have only 15372 datasets. In my opinion the result displays, each dataset is unique, right?

Comment: No, the values will be 1,2,3. Number assocoated with the point number is the cluster in the data. For example, if you have a resulting array like `[3,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0]` then your first data point belongs to third cluster, second to 0th, third to 0 and so on..

Comment: No, the values will be 1,2,3. Number assocoated with the point number is the cluster in the data. For example, if you have a resulting array like `[3,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0]` then your first data point belongs to third cluster, second to 0th, third to 0 and so on..

Comment: If I take up your example and do something like this `np.unique([3,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0])`, the result will be `(0,1,2,3)` and then will `len(np.unique([3,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0]))` = 4. So, the dataset was clustered in four different clusters.I understand that `([3,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0])` shows, which array is belonging to which cluster. Then, the different values in `([3,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0])` are the different clusters.

Comment: No, Each data point belongs to `this` cluster. The number 0,1,2,3 are nothing but a way of saying `cluster_number`. `[3,0,0]` = [c3,c0,c0] ` What you can do is `df['clusters_number'] = clustering.labels_ ` (except berch)